# Is Han Solo a criminal in the New Republic?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, han-solo

In Legends, we know that as the Rebellion transits into a Republic, their relations with smugglers etc. grew tense and eventually broke up because smugglers are criminals under any galactic government's law. Smugglers only helped the Rebellion because a Republic is easier to operate in than an Empire.

That is in Legends, but the same principles apply to the New Republic of canon. We know that at some point, Han Solo went back to smuggling - "doing what he does best". As such, is he as a smuggler a New Republic criminal and maybe even a fugitive?

Comment: Note that  your question has something of a false premise; smugglers like Han don't carry _only_ illegal cargoes (unless working for Jabba the Hutt exclusively), they're cargo carriers who will, if the money is right, carry things deemed illegal by their destinations (or maybe just to avoid import duties).  Outside of item-related ideologies (ie, food for oppressed people), many smugglers would have been helping the rebellion because they were paid.  The rebellion, of course, used smugglers because 'legitimate' haulers would report them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the factbooks released alongside the film, Han has indeed returned to a life of crime.

From [Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

> After the Galactic Civil War, Han Solo's life took unexpected turns as
>   he became husband to an influential New Republic politician, a family
>   man and - for a time - successful racing pilot. But the peace of this
>   life as not to last, and after a profound tragedy upended what had
>   become normal for the Corellian, **Solo returned to his old life as a
>   tramp freighter captain, smuggler and freelance law bender.**

and

> As easily as the Millennium Falcon fell into Solo's life after a
>   heated game of sabacc, so it was destined to abandon him after a
>   change in fate. Solo made do with other ships at his disposal,
>   eventually settling on an enormous bulk freighter named the Eravana,
>   **which he uses to haul massive shipments of legally questionable cargo.** The ship is largely automated, meaning Solo and Chewbacca can
>   handle most of the work, but on particularly dangerous or profitable
>   hauls he hires additional hands.

From [Star Wars: Incredible Cross Sections - The Force Awakens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1465438157) we see that Han is carrying stolen items, illegal speeders and black-market animals such as [Rathtars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rathtar).

[image: Millenium Falcon cross-section]

The film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization)) also makes note that they're instantly identifiable as smugglers

> ***The pair who came aboard the Millennium Falcon were not stormtroopers
>   but smugglers.*** One was old, human, and somewhat scruffy-looking. The
>   other was almost a half-meter taller and much hairier. They entered
>   the freighter with a measure of fondness and caution, as it had been a
>   long time since they’d walked down her corridors.

Comment: +1, though I would say that your quoted sources seem to go out of their way to emphasize that he's at the boundaries of the law rather than an full-on criminal. He's a "law bender" who smuggles "legally questionable cargo" that may be highly profitable and may involve missions/routes that are "particularly dangerous". Doesn't mean he couldn't be thrown in jail or fined for many of his actions, so he's a criminal. Though it may also be that the laws he choses to break are made by folks who are themselves criminals or oppressive.

Comment: @Wayne hmm, valid points. Legally questionable cargo can mean different things. I quote from some space games I played before in the past: Goods can be divided into more than just legal & illegal. They can be legal, legal with tariff, declaration and/or license, or prohibited. It can also apply only to certain star systems rather than the whole galaxy. Besides uncontrolled goods, you'd need a smuggler to sneak anything else past the customs unnoticed.

Comment: I would also question whether he does any of his smuggling within the New Republic.  It doesn't seem like any of the planets we see him on/near are affiliated.

Comment: @MatthewRead - Sure, because most criminals are very particular about who they steal from.

Comment: Like those who don't want to be caught?  The Outer Rim and other remote places are *always* depicted as being the focus of smuggling and other crime because people can get away with it.  And you really don't think Han might have any issues ever with stealing from the people he fought to free?  (You have also provided zero evidence of Han *stealing* anything, so I'm not sure how that is relevant.)

Comment: @MatthewRead - Smuggling is usually characterised by a failure to pay appropriate taxes or duties. That's a form of theft against the state.

Comment: Some would argue smuggling is resisting attempts of theft *by* the state.

Comment: @Michael - If you don't like paying certain taxes, the appropriate way to protest is by voting for someone who'll repeal them for you.

Comment: @Richard That's one type of smuggling (whether it's the most common, I have no idea); another one, which seems to generally fit better with Han's MO, is transporting cargo (including people) in or out of places they are not allowed to enter/leave, which is quite unrelated to duties and taxes. No less illegal, but not about duty or tax evasion.

Comment: Essentially everything mentioned falls within the framework I mentioned. Han transports goods to places that is either outright prohibited or would be without going through due procedure, which the client refuses to do. Whatever the case, I doubt he distinguishes by territory. That cuts out a whole lot of potential business, not to mention how the New Republic took over almost all Imperial space - the only major areas left is the Unknown Regions & Wild Space.

Comment: @MatthewRead It seems more to me that the Outer Rim is where crimes typical to Third World nations take place, while the Core and Inner Rim is where crimes typical to First World nations take place. Arms smuggling is probably more prevalent in the Outer Rim, while drugs smuggling is probably more prevalent in the Core Worlds.